# Htaccess redirect not successfully working

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am currently creating a site in localhost and have no luck in getting redirect working. I want to redirect

```
http://localhost/s/profile.php?uid=16
```

to

```
http://localhost/s/16
```

How could I go about doing this. I have tried using examples online with no luck.

Edit: I tried

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /s/profile.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

Using copy and paste from online. I always try to figure out who to use htaccess but can't seem to do so.

Comment: What have you actually tried? Post your failed attempts and then we'll try to help.

Comment: I tried RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /s/profile.php?uid=$1 [L]

Comment: Where is your htaccess file?

Comment: @JonLin it's at the root of the s folder

Answer (score 0):

Here is the base functionality you are looking for. This is just a simple example and you should certainly do your research on this subject.

Alternatively, there are plenty of generators. 
http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ - [L,NE]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /profile.php [L,NE]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this rule

```
RewriteRule ^s/([^/]*)/?$ /s/profile.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You want me to remove it?

Comment: Yes replace your current rule with above

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your "s" folder, try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+s/profile\.php\?uid=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /s/%1.php? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php$ /s/profile.php?uid=$1 [L]
```